# How to scale the dots of a graph based on their p-value in R?

Tags: r, plot, graph, dataframe

I have a data.frame named `df.ordered` that looks like:

```
             labels        gvs order color pvals
1            Adygei -2.3321916     1     1 0.914
2            Basque -0.8519079     2     1 0.218
3            French -0.9298674     3     1 0.000
4           Italian -2.8859587     4     1 0.024
5          Orcadian -1.4996229     5     1 0.148
6           Russian -1.5597359     6     1 0.626
7         Sardinian -1.4494841     7     1 0.516
8            Tuscan -2.4279528     8     1 0.420
9           Bedouin -3.1717421     9     2 0.914
10            Druze -0.5058627    10     2 0.220
11         Mozabite -2.6491331    11     2 0.200
12      Palestinian -0.7819299    12     2 0.552
13          Balochi -1.4095947    13     3 0.158
14           Brahui -1.2534511    14     3 0.162
15          Burusho  1.7958170    15     3 0.414
16           Hazara  2.2810477    16     3 0.152
17           Kalash -0.9258497    17     3 0.974
18          Makrani -0.9007551    18     3 0.226
19           Pathan  2.5543214    19     3 0.112
20           Sindhi  2.6614486    20     3 0.338
21            Uygur -1.2207974    21     3 0.652
22        Cambodian  2.3706977    22     4 0.118
23              Dai -0.9441980    23     4 0.686
24             Daur -1.0325107    24     4 0.932
25              Han -0.7381369    25     4 0.794
26           Hezhen -2.7590587    26     4 0.182
27         Japanese -0.5644325    27     4 0.366
28             Lahu -0.8449225    28     4 0.560
29             Miao -0.7237586    29     4 0.194
30          Mongola -0.9452944    30     4 0.768
31             Naxi -0.1625003    31     4 0.554
32           Oroqen -1.2035258    32     4 0.782
33              She -2.7758460    33     4 0.912
34               Tu -0.7703779    34     4 0.254
35            Tujia -1.0265275    35     4 0.912
36             Xibo -1.1163019    36     4 0.292
37            Yakut -3.2102686    37     4 0.030
38               Yi -0.9614190    38     4 0.838
39        Colombian -1.9659984    39     5 0.166
40        Karitiana -0.9195156    40     5 0.660
41             Maya  2.1239768    41     5 0.818
42             Pima -3.0895998    42     5 0.818
43            Surui -0.9377928    43     5 0.536
44       Melanesian -1.6961014    44     6 0.414
45           Papuan -0.7037952    45     6 0.386
46       BantuKenya -1.9311354    46     7 0.484
47 BantuSouthAfrica -1.8515908    47     7 0.016
48       BiakaPygmy -1.7657017    48     7 0.538
49         Mandenka -0.5423822    49     7 0.076
50       MbutiPygmy -1.6244801    50     7 0.054
51              San -0.9049735    51     7 0.478
52           Yoruba  2.0949378    52     7 0.904
```

I have made the following graph
[image]

I used the code:

```
jpeg("test3.jpg", 700,700)
df.ordered$color <- as.factor(df.ordered$color)
levels(df.ordered$color) <- c("blue","yellow3","red","pink","purple","green","orange")
plot(df.ordered$gvs, pch = 19, cex=2, col = as.character(df.ordered$color), xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=1:52, col=as.character(df.ordered$color),labels=df.ordered$labels, las=2)
dev.off()
```

I now want to scale the dots of the graph to the `pvals` column. I want the low pvalues to be larger dots, and the higher p-value to be the smaller dots. One issue is that some pvalues are 0. I was thinking of turning all `pvals` values that are 0.000 to 0.001 to fix this. Does anyone know how to do this? I want the graph to look similar to the graph in figure 5 here: http://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1004412

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cex` argument is vectorized, i.e., you can pass in a vector (of the same length of your data to plot). Take this as a simple example:

```
plot(1:5, cex = 1:5)
```

[image]

Now, it is completely up to you to define a relationship between `cex` and `pvals`. How about `a + (1 - pvals) * (b - a)`? This will map `1-pvals` from `[0,1]` to `[a,b]`. For example, with `a = 1, b = 5`, you can try:

```
cex <- 1 + (1 - df.ordered$pvals) * (5 - 1)
```

> I'm looking to have the p-values between 0.000 and 0.0010 to have cex = ~10, p-values between 0.010 and 0.20 to have cex = ~5, and p-values from 0.20-1.00 to have cex = ~0.5.

I recommend using `cut()`:

```
fac <- cut(df.ordered$pvals, breaks = c(0, 0.001, 0.2, 1),
           labels = c(10, 5, 0.5), right = FALSE)
cex <- c(10, 5, 0.5)[as.integer(fac)]
```

Comment: I'm confused what the `set.seed(); pvals <- rebta(10,3,5)` dos? Also since I want the lowest pvalue to be the largest just set `size.frame= (1-round(pvals,1)`, and then `cex = size.fame`?

Comment: I'm having a very difficult time getting the size separation that I see in Figure 5 in this paper http://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1004412. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: this question wasn't asked in this post, but do you have any thoughts on how I would get the labels to correspond to the colors of their dots? Here is what the graph looks like now: http://imgur.com/a/jmBaE

Comment: yeah, if the words on the x-axis could be the same color as their dots

Comment: Current the code I'm using to make the graph is: `jpeg("GVS.trait.Jul_20.jpg", 700,700)
final$color <- as.factor(final$color)
levels(final$color) <- c("blue","yellow3","red","pink","purple","green","orange")
plot(final$gvs, pch = 21, cex=size, bg = as.character(final$color), xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="Genetic Value", main="Trait")
axis(1, at=1:52, col=as.character(final$color),labels=final$labels, las=2)
dev.off()`

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @zheyuan-li's answer, here is a normalization that puts the size of the points for p-values "equal" to 0 with size 2, and the point size of observations with p-values "equal" to 1 with size zero:

```
plot(df.ordered$gvs, pch = 19,
     cex=2 * (1-df.ordered$pvals)/(df.ordered$pvals +1),
     col = as.character(df.ordered$color), xaxt="n")
```

[image]

Comment: @Imo, this is a great answer! I'm looking to have the pvalues between 0.000 and 0.0010 to have Cex = ~10, pvalues between 0.010 and 0.20 to have cex=~5, and pvalues from 0.20-1.00 to have cex = ~0.5. Does anything come to mind?

Comment: @Evan You could write a function with `ifelse` for such a mapping, something like `myFun <- function(x) {ifelse(x < .001, 10, ifelse(x < .2, 5, .5))}` should work.